# How to use Indicator variable in PROC UCM?

Tags: sas, regression, forecasting, dummy-variable

I want to use an indicator variables in Proc UCM. I have a weekly volume  and i want to use days as indicator variables because if public holiday  is fall in Wednesdays or Thursday then  the  rate of decrease in volume is and much higher than the Friday  holiday impact.So how can i create a indicator variable for weekdays. MON TUE WEN THU FRI.I am making MON=1 if holiday is on MON else zero same rule for all.Will there be an issue of dummy trap if i include all the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to safely use the variables; however, I would recommend trying to use a trigonometric cyclical component of period 7 and seeing how it fares. If you'd like to do the dummy approach, you can do so in the data step prior to running the model:

```
data want;
    set have;
    array weekday[*] Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat

    do i = 1 to 6;
        weekday[i] = (weekday(date) = i);
    end;

    ThxGiving = (date = holiday('THANKSGIVING', year(date) ) );
run;

proc ucm data=want;
    model y = mon tue wed thu fri sat ThxGiving;
        level;
        irregular;
run;
```

Your `MON-SAT` variables will capture the daily effects, while `ThxGiving` will capture the unique effect of both natural Thursday demand and Thanksgiving.  I would not expect dummy trap to be a problem here, because normal Thursdays will not likely be able to predict Thanksgiving demand, and vis-versa.

Again, I would first recommend trying to include a cyclical trig pattern for weekday before going the dummy variable route.

```
proc ucm data=want;
    model y = ThxGiving;
        cycle period=7;
        level;
        irregular;
run;
```